# Sensor Data Input into MySQL via Python, raspberry pi

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi3

So I am having an issue where I believe the py program is connecting, but the data is not in the tables/database as recorded. I realize my code is crappy, I am flying a little blind.
I have apache2, MariaDB, and PHPMyAdmin through the raspberry pi.
I am trying to have the sensor read the temp/humidity every 5 mins and then log the value in the database. I hadn't got to the 5 minutes yet, I was just looking to ensure the data is being recorded first. I am using Thonny on the pi and trawling the internet for solutions

I have a database called "sensor" with the table "sensordht" with the Columns: ID, timestamp, temperature, and humidity.

If anyone could help me with the input data/how to input data every 5 mins, that would be ace.
Help me, internet wizards, you're my only hope.

````
import time
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import MySQLdb
import datetime
import os
from time import strftime
                       
timestamp = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y @ %H:%M:%S")
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11
sensor_pin = 4
running = True
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost",user= "root",passwd="Hummus9",db="sensor")
c = conn.cursor()

try:
 if humidity is None and temperature is None:
                         c.execute("INSERT INTO sensordht(timestamp, temperature, humidity) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",(timestamp, temperature, humidity))
                         conn.commit()
                         c.close
     
 else:
                         print('Failed to get reading')
                         sys.exit(1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
 print ('Program stopped')
 running = False
 file.close() ```
````

Comment: Basic debugging: is your code getting any sensor data; if so, are there errors occurring in you calls to MySQL?

Comment: if i put print with timestamp and the temp/humidity it works.